# Fatal error while executing HDMan command

Tags: fatal-error, htk

I am trying to use `HDMan` command of htk toolkit but getting 'fatal' error. 
My console looks like below :

```
shekhar@ubuntu:/host/Shekhar/htkWorld/trial_1$ ls
beep  dlog         sentences (copy).txt  sentences.txt~                         try1.gram  wlist
dict  monophones1  sentences.txt         sentences (with sentence numbers).txt  wdnet      wlist~
shekhar@ubuntu:/host/Shekhar/htkWorld/trial_1$ HDMan -m -w wlist -n monophones1 -l dlog dict beep/beep-1.0 names
  ERROR [+5010]  InitSource: Cannot open source file names
  ERROR [+1410]  CreateBuffer: Can't open file names
 FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HDMan
shekhar@ubuntu:/host/Shekhar/htkWorld/trial_1$
```

`HDMan` is not able to find `names` file. I do not know how to create this file and what will be the contents of this file.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDMan is used to pull together pronunciations from various dictionaries and is invoked as

```
HDMan [options] output_dictionary input_dictionary1 input_dictionary2 ...
```

It looks like you are trying to create a new dictionary named dict from beep/beep-1.0 and names. Names does not exist and that is where the error comes from. Simply removing names should fix the error.

If you actually do need pronunciations from a dictionary called names, then that will be an issue later in the process. Without more information, it is impossible to know what the contents of that file should be. In general, format for the file is

```
WORD [optional pronunciation probability] phone1 phone2 ...
```

and each line contains only one such entry.